# How to remap array values of a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two arrays provided as params to the SQL query. I want to take out all existing values from the table and replace with the new if they are matching.

column `values` is `jsonb[]` type.

i.e.

```
old_vals [1,2,3]
new_vals [4,5]

values (BEFORE)
'{1,2,3}'
'{2}'
'{3}'

RUN QUERY

values (AFTER)
'{4,5}'
'{5}'
NULL
```

So far I managed to prepare such SQL statement:

```
UPDATE db.table 
    SET "values" = subquery.newValues
    FROM (
           SELECT $1::jsonb[] AS newValues
    ) AS subquery
    WHERE id = 'some_id';
```

the problem right now is that this query doesn't remap the values but override them with params from `$1`, the solution I'm looking for is to only provide a part (or none) of the values matching the index in the `old_vals` array.

Any ideas how to improve that?